# Upload file to server ionic and php

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I have code that sends an image to my server and everything works fine. However i am now truing to send a file to my server using an input tag in ionic However i cant seem to get it working.

I get an error from the php file saying undefined index 'file'
[image: Error message]
[image: Response]
**HTML**

```
<ion-col>
    <ion-label>Add a File</ion-label>
    <ion-input type='file' [(ngModel)]="fileName"></ion-input>
</ion-col>
```

**TS file**

```
addFile() {
    this.addService.addFile(this.fileName).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

**service**

```
addFile(file) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', '' + this.token);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    return this.http.post<any>('http://domain.fileUpload.php', formData, {headers});
}
```

**PHP API**

```
$target_path = "files/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
$findDate = date("Y-m-d");

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {             
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Upload and move success'];

    echo json_encode( $data );

} else {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $data = ['success' => false, 'message' => 'There was an error uploading the file (folder), please try again!'];
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

uploadMethod

```
uploadFile: ''; // from ngModel
fileUpload(path) {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: '.png',
      chunkedMode: false,
    };

    console.log(this.uploadFile);

    fileTransfer
      .upload(this.uploadFile, 'http://domain/fileUpload.php',
        options
      )
      .then(
        data => {
          console.log(data + 'Uploaded Successfully');
          // console.log(JSON.parse(data.));
          // let res = JSON.parse(data);
          let res = data;
          if (res['success']) {
            console.log('True');
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Does `addFile` throws an error ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add error. Have edited it above

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace ?

Comment: Added images above in edit

Comment: Use this Plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

Comment: Hi when i looked into this it says it is deprecated? Will it still work ok?

Comment: Yes, it will work. and it is not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Blow is the Example Code:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

checkPlatform: boolean = fasle;

constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
      this.checkPlatform == true; // if platform ios this will be true
    }
    if (this.plt.is('android')) {
      this.checkPlatform == true; // if platform androidthis will be true
    }

  }

imageUpload(path) {
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: 'image',
      fileName: '.png',
      chunkedMode: false,
      //mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    }


    fileTransfer.upload(path, 'https://yourDomain.com/api/imageUpload', options)
      .then((data) => {
      console.log(data+" Uploaded Successfully");
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.response));
      let res = JSON.parse(data.response);
      if (res.success == true) {
          // do whats ever you want to do
      }


    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);

    });
}
```

Pass the cordova file path as parameter in this function.

inside you HTML template show buttons or input type like this:

```
<input type="file" *ngIf="checkPlatform == true">
```

Comment: getting this error FileTransferError {code: 1, source: "C:\fakepath\panda.jpg", target: "http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/fileUpload.php", http_status: null, body: null, …}

Comment: Edited above for the upload function

Comment: what is in your `this.uploadFile` please share

Comment: It is coming from the input tag ngModel getting the file

Comment: Input type `file` might have some issues.. if it is only Image please use Camera Plugin.

Comment: Or use this Plugin for other files: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-chooser/

Comment: No it is for other non image files. Isn't file chooser only for android?

Comment: But what about browser?

Comment: You can wrap it in `platform` api with `*ngIf=''`

Comment: Sorry i mean how to upload with browser too?

Comment: I understand but if they are on a browser how can they upload files? These options are only for mobile?

Comment: use `ionic cordova platform add  browser` module.

Answer (score 0):

if you see [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/interface.d.ts#L40) you can notice allowed types are :

`export type TextFieldTypes = 'date' | 'email' | 'number' | 'password' | 'search' | 'tel' | 'text' | 'url' | 'time';`

if you want to upload files follow [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) link i think you will find the answer

Comment: Hi ive been looking everywhere for an example to follow for the file plugin but cant seem to find one

Comment: follow the link i've added to upload files , it's documented well

Comment: It is just the file plugin? There is no upload eg?

Comment: if you want to upload file use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: I have tried that but cant get it working? Its in the code above

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and as i see `file` added to `FormData` is filename with `string` Type, not `File` or `Blob` Data Type. So in this case it will not send file into `$_FILES`, it actually send its value to `$_POST` in your `PHP Server`. In summary, `File` and `Blob` Type will be sent to `$_FILES`, other data types will be sent to the appropriate global variables.

There is also a good example on how to validate your file in `PHP Server`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: So i just change my formData to a file or blob?

Comment: That's right. When you upload your file via `HTML` tags, it's actually `blob` type that you can append to `DataForm`.